# Assembly language, please explain

Tags: assembly

I'm studying for an exam and this is confusing me. Could anyone explain this to me?

```
mov AX,10  ;load 10 into ax.
shl AX,1   ;shift ax left 1 which is 100.
add AX,10  ;add 10 which is 110.
cmp AX,10  ;this is were i get lost.
dec ax     ;decrement ax.
```

The answer is 29. Why is this?

Comment: The computer works in binary, so `shl` shifts the *binary* representation of `10` left, which is `1010`. This becomes `10100`, which is `20` is decimal notation, not `110`.

Comment: thanks, how did you do that, took me 20mins before it would let me post the question

Comment: thanks for the ans. It wouldnt let me leave the question as assembly language. I had to put it as sentances. Thanks for the answer cheers

Comment: If you look in the online help for this site it explains how to format your questions. Different assemblers might have slightly different syntax to represent numbers in different bases, but a number without other annotations is usually decimal. So `10` in this context is decimal. Hexadecimal is usually `10h` or `0x10`. Binary might be `10b` or `0b10` or `10y` or `0y10` (using NASM, for instance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AX is an x86 16bit register.

1. `mov AX,10  ;load 10 into ax.`
   MOVe
   Copy the *decimal* value 10 from instruction operand to register AX.
   ***AX=0000 1010 (binary) = 10 (decimal)***
2. `shl AX,1   ;shift ax left 1 which is 100.`
   SHift Left
   Shift the AX register bits to the left by inserting 1 zero digit from the right, this is an old trick to perform multiplication by 2.
   ***AX=0001 0100 (binary) = 20 (decimal)***
3. `add AX,10  ;add 10 which is 110.`
   ADD
   Add the immediate value to register AX, AX = AX + 10.
   ***AX=0001 1110 (binary) = 30 (decimal)***
4. `cmp AX,10  ;this is were i get lost.`
   CoMPare
   Subtract the immediate value from register AX but *don't save the result*, just update the processor flags. Used to perform jumps.
   ***AX=0001 1110 (binary) = 30 (decimal), plus ZF=0, CF=0, AF=0, PF=0, SF=0, OF=0***
5. `dec ax; decrement ax`
   DECrement
   Subtract 1 from AX.
   ***AX=0001 1101 (binary) = 29 (decimal)***

In the first instruction the numeral '10' is interpreted as decimal. Usually assemblers follow or the TASM/NASM/MASM convention ('10' is decimal, '10d' is also decimal, '10h' is hexadecimal, '10o' is octal, 10b is binary, 10y is binary) or the C convention ('10' is decimal, '0x10' is hexadecimal, '010' is octal, '0b10' is binary) or both.

The compare instruction is just a subtraction that doesn't store the result. If you think about it, given two number A and B, by computing A-B you can tell if A=B (because A-B would be 0) or A>B (A-B would be >0) or A<B (because A-B would need a borrow to be computed, i.e. it's negative).

The flags ZF (Zero flag) and CF (Carry Flag) just record the fact that the last operation produced a zero result or needed a borrow/produced a carry (to see why borrow and carry are the same, just refer to *two complement* and *full adders*).
Every instruction either update some of the flags (like add, sub, mul, inc, test, ...) or leave them unaffected (mov for example update no flag).

Flags are used for conditional jumps (like ja, jb, je, ...).

By the way, though the CMP instruction before the DEC is not strictly useless (DEC doesn't update the CF flag) it's likely that it is there just to confuse you.